# Python isn't ignoring the word in file

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python so I get stuck often and if this is an easy fix please tell me.

I'm working on a project where my program is gonna recognize and compare words from a file. I thought this would be easy for a beginner like me, but my problem is that the program is recognizing "User" as a user and I'm probably very picky or something but it irritates me.

This is the code I tried from another StackOverflow question but it doesn't seem to work with file reading.

```
import re

mytext = open ("Secret.txt", "r")

#The Text i'm gonna ignore                   
r_items=['User']

mytext = [x for x in mytext if x not in r_items]
```

what I expected was that Python would ignore the word "User" but I assume need to do something else.

Comment: `mytext` is a sequence of characters, not words.

Comment: Hi LuckyZakary! I am not getting an error the problem is that when i type in “User” on my input the Program is recognizing it as an username it would look something like this:

Username: User
Password:

Comment: If an answer helps solve your problem, you can accept it by clicking the check mark.

Comment: How do *you* think the for loop is 'splitting' the text from the file into an iterable? Remove your comprehension and start with that. `for x in mytext: print("---", x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `str.replace` method, like this.

```py
banned_words = ['User']

# Always use `with` to open files, 
# so it's automatically closed when finished.
with open('Secrets.txt') as f:
    # Read all the text into a string.
    text = f.read()

# Iterate over the banned words.
for banned_word in banned_words:
    # Reassign `text` to the new version without `banned_word`.
    text = text.replace(text, banned_word, '')

print(text)
```

Comment: The reason you were probably downvoted is the fact the you restructured the code (`with`-statement, `.read()`-method) without explanation and you also did not explain why his approach did not work. If you add these, you might get more upvotes (at least one from me ;-) )

Comment: Makes sense. Done.